# How to ignore an error in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, null, userscripts

I am running a Tampermonkey script on a website that I do not have the code for.

Sometimes it happens that I have a value that does not exist on the page and I get the following error:
"Cannot read property 'click' of null"

And the entire script stops. How can I tell get my script to ignore the error and just carry on to the next line of code?

Here is an example of a vanilla Javascript line that I work with:

```js
document.querySelector('[value="xyz"]').click();
```

Comment: Check if there’s a value with an “if” and don’t try to click it if there isn’t?

Comment: The only thing you can do is wrap the line(s) that cause the error(s) in `try/catch`.

Comment: `const elem = document.querySelector('[value="xyz"]'); elem && elem.click();`

Comment: @ScottMarcus ...or some equivalent of `if (element) element.click()`

Answer (score 3):

Only execute `click()` if the selector found something:

```
if(document.querySelector('[value="xyz"]'))
    document.querySelector('[value="xyz"]').click();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Ismael - this is a good idea. I will go and try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and you shouldn't want to: errors are bad. They're not informative, *they are a signal that the code has run into an unrecoverable error* and the current code path should be terminated. If you were to ignore it, and keep running, now you're in a state where any subsequent line is just as likely to also throw an error.

Either actually fix things, by making your tampermonkey script not interfere with the way the page it's running on builds its DOM, or as a last resort, you can find out which function is throwing the error for the specific page(s) you're running into this, and then _specifically for those pages, find and rebind the entire function using a try/catch, such as:

```
const _old_fn = window.theFunctionInvolved;
window.theFunctionInvolved = function(...args) {
    try { return _old_fn(...args); }
    catch (e) {}
};
```

But of course, all you've now done is moved the buck: you'll have effectively guaranteed different errors later on, with the actual cause now permanently hidden.

So really: don't do this. Fix your tampermonkey script, or stop using it altogether.

Comment: Thank you Mike, you are right - errors are an indication that something is wrong. As a matter of fact, it helped me to find this error. I will see if I can fix my Tampermonkey script.